# What is this particular distribution in random matrix theory?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

In a certain statistical problem involving large random matrices, I recently encountered the distribution on the picture below. I did not manage to identify it after browsing the internet for quite some time. I tried to use the method of moments but ended up with computations that lead apparently nowhere. Extensive use of Mathematica for the latter computations did not help either.

Have you ever encountered such a distribution ? Can you tell me what it is ?

Thanks in advance. [image: Eigenvalue distribution]

Comment: Isn't that the Kesten--McKay distribution? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379581901506

Comment: It reminds me of the distribution of symmetric matrices following a quartic distribution (instead of gaussian): $\exp\left\{-N \operatorname{Tr}\left(\frac{1}{2} M^{2}+\alpha M^{4} \right)\right\}$. Figure 3 in this review presents a similar shape: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-5468/aba499/pdf?casa_token=bVfqdaVJ_94AAAAA:fShjXOn83mISzPyPybjNQNgHHYUJgNe941-1GKmTeZstL9n21CghX5GKZ_pLcrtOaFmNgswnYwx_73Z9. Hope this helps! Edit: The Kesten--McKay looks like a better candidate.

Comment: It looks extremely promising, thank you so much SeanEberhard and Matt !